# How to find the BIOS serial number on Windows 98?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, wmi, windows-98

In Windows 10 I can use WMI, but it seems that Microsoft has removed this download from their website which supports Windows 98. I need to use it for a legacy project.

Any ideas, or other tool recommendation I can use? I am looking for command-line solutions.

**Edit**
I am trying to identify a PC ranging from Windows 98 to 10. I think that the serial number of the BIOS might be a good option.

Comment: try archive.org to find it

Comment: Not sure if this is stored in the registry in win-98 but have you checked `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System`

Comment: Thank you Yorik, yes it is also available on Windows 98. But there is no "Bios" folder like in Windows 10. I was thinking that the best way to identify a PC would be to use the BIOS serial number. What do you think?

Comment: What BIOS serial number would you be talking about? How do you retrieve it on Windows 10?

Comment: @DanielB I am using the following cmd command in Windows 10 to retrieve it: `WMIC bios get serialnumber`. I mean the hardware serial number which identifies the BIOS.

Comment: Right, “To Be Filled By O.E.M.”. It you’re looking to identify PCs, you’ll want to use different means to get a (sort-of) unique fingerprint. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/99880/1025421).

Answer (score 0):

To enter the BIOS, press the appropriate key (e.g. DEL) (on some systems, F1 or F2 or F11) repeatedly at startup. Then read the serial number from the BIOS screen.

Alternatively, the program **BIOS.EXE v1.35** (24 KB) will save the computer's BIOS settings to a file (e.g. save it to Drive D).

Syntax -

```
BIOS.EXE S D:\CMOS.BIN
```

You can then, for example, inspect the saved data in a hex editor.

*Note* -
Do NOT run this EXE file in a Windows DOS box. The BIOS is divided in two parts: the first contains procedures only needed while booting, the second contains all other procedures. The first part of the BIOS segment is used as conventional memory after booting. If you try to make a BIOS dump from within Win9x, you get a dump file with some normal memory and the second part of the BIOS; the first part is missing.

See this link: http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/bridip/recovery.htm

Or this link: https://www.mediafire.com/?2myc4jlf5h1qo

Alternatively, you might find this tool helpful:

**CrystalDMI 1.0.5** from http://www.brothersoft.com/crystaldmi-162969.html